# How to set an object attribute's value based on another attributes value?

Tags: java, java-stream

What would be the equivalent lambda expression for streaming through a list of objects.  Then checking an objects attribute for a value and setting another attribute in the same object based on that value.  Example:

```
List<OptionOverrideChangeOrderModel> quoteOptions = 
Collections.singletonList(quoteOption);
        
for (OptionOverrideChangeOrderModel option : quoteOptions) {
    if (option.getFet() > 0) {
        option.setApplyFet(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be:

```
quoteOptions
  .stream()
  .filter(el -> el.getFet() > 0)
  .foreach(el -> el.setApplyFet(true))
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto!

Comment: @TonyNeves feel free to mark this as correct